# My bare metal PC hangs at the ubuntu logo when booting, rtx3060ti gcard

Tags: boot, grub2, files, log

I have looked through other posts and answers, my problem seems a little different in that there is, or was, no option in the update gui to change any 3rd party drivers at all. None were displayed, and then suddenly the hanging on boot started.

I wonder could someone help me to locate the appropriate log files from the command line available in recovery mode? I have looked, but there is over 250 gigs of files on the partition I mounted for /var. Is this quantity normal?

I've been at it for 5 days now, so any pointers would be good just to diagnose the problem, as it was working fine for 2 weeks.

Comment: Check the size of the files in /var/log (< 100MB).  Something seems out of hand if /var is 250GB.  I suppose check /var/backups too  ( a few meg)

Comment: Thanks. I've got a much clearer view of whats happening